# "Decirme" or "me decir" after an auxiliary verb

Tags: verbos, pronombres

We came in contact with the following question: how could we translate the following statement from English to Spanish:

> She will want to tell me (...)

However, during this, we couldn't find whether the first or the second one of the following statements is the correct one, even though we searched:

> Ella querrá decirme (...)

Or

> Ella querrá me decir (...)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know (I'm not a native speaker), you can use either

- Ella querrá decirme
- Ella me querrá decir

See the [Wikipedia page on Spanish object pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_object_pronouns#Usage):

> In constructions that make use of infinitives or gerunds as arguments of a conjugated verb, clitic pronouns may appear as proclitics before the verb (as in most verbal constructions) or simply as enclitics attached to the infinitive or gerund itself. Similarly, in combinations of infinitives, enclitics may attach to any one infinitive:
>
> - Quería hacerlo or Lo quería hacer = "He wanted to do it"

Comment: And about this statement: "Cuando se tomó esta foto?", is it correct?

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo It's okay.

Answer (score 2):

**The correct thing to say would be "Decirme"** not "me decir". **I am a native speaker**, the "me" is for who or what is received. The "me" is an unstressed pronoun, it is always accompanied by something else, you can't say in Spanish "¿Quién fue?" and answer "me" you would have to say "yo", the "yo" would be a tonic pronoun and unlike the "me" it could be used alone in a sentence. "Decirme" is not a conjugation of "decir", but an infinitive plus an atonic pronoun, as I said before, the "me" can go in front if there is another verb, like here "Ella me querrá decir" this would be correct, what would not be correct would be "Elle querrá me decir".

**Perhaps my answer resents the fact that I am a native Spaniard**, I'm sorry. I hope I have helped you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an auxiliary verb, the object pronoun will go either *before the auxiliary* or *after the main verb.*

The sentence I always use to illustrate this rule is:

**Me volveré a bañar.**

You can also say:

**Volveré a bañarme.**

Placing the object pronoun before an infinitive (**me bañar**) was common in Medieval Spanish, but no one does that anymore.

If you add more auxiliary verbs, the pattern does not change much:

**Me tengo que volver a bañar.**

Or:

**Tengo que volver a bañarme.**

It would sound a bit odd, but still acceptable, to say:

**Tengo que volverme a bañar.**

If you add yet another auxiliary verb, the pattern remains similar:

**Me voy a tener que volver a bañar.**

It's perfectly fine to say instead:

**Voy a tener que volver a bañarme.**

It would be less common, but still acceptable, to say:

**Voy a tener que volverme a bañar.**

And it would be technically correct but super weird to say:

**Voy a tenerme que volver a bañar.**

In all cases, the object pronoun is placed *before a conjugated form* or *after an infinitive*. Any other position (**voyme** or **me tener**) is obsolete.